# i need to get specific word from word using it's position

Tags: java, string

i Have String Like This.

```
Hello World!. Hey There
```

here "world" is at 2nd position & "There" is at 5th position How do i get that word at specific position in java.

Comment: It is easy,have you tried anything, where is your wrong code.

Comment: Also can you tell how there is at 5th position,instead of 4th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello World!. Hey There

1. Hello
2. World
3. Hey
4. There

***P.S.*** I do not think that you treat `!.` as a separate word

```
String str = "Hello World!. Hey There";
String[] parts = str.split("\\W+");
String secondWord = parts[1];
```

Do use *regular expression* to detect your word separators. In my example this is `\W+` which is `one or more not-word characters`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the basis of the space and it will return the array of string. Now we can retrieve the position string via the `(position - 1)`

```
String stringObj = "Hello World!. Hey There";
String stringObj[] = stringObj.spilt(" ");

String requiredString = stringObj[position - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*@input: is the source string to search* 
      * @word is the key to search 
      * @returns the position of the word if prsent else -1 is returned
      */
     public static int wordPosition(String input,String word)
    {

        String[] result=input.split(" ");
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++)
        {   if(result[i].contains(word))
                return i+1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```